# C# ternary operator List operator

Tags: c#, list, operator-keyword, ternary-operator

Any knows a quickest Ternary operation for this.

```
label1.Text = Cclass.TestMe()
                    .Where(t => t.GFName == (textBox1.Text == "" 
                                              ? "GName" 
                                              : textBox1.Text))
                    .First()
                    .GFName == null ? 
              "Nothing" : 
              "Super";
```

I was trying to check if the List is empty return something. So the compiler will not throw a Exception or unhanded error.

Comment: And what problem are you having with this code?

Comment: Not everything needs to be done in a single statement....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***reason*** of this ***exception*** is [`First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535050%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It will throw an exception if there's no row to be returned. Instead of that you can use [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which will return the default value *(NULL for all reference types)* instead. But if you want to check if there any element inside your list which mathcing the condition, then you must use [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method:

```
 return Cclass.TestMe()
                .Any(t => t.GFName == (textBox1.Text == "" ? "GName" : textBox1.Text)) ? 
        "Super" : 
        "Nothing";
```

By the way, it would be better to set text outside of your query:

```
var filteredText = textBox1.Text == "" ? "GName" : textBox1.Text;
return Cclass.TestMe().Any(t => t.GFName == filteredText) ? 
            "Super" : 
            "Nothing";
```

Comment: @DStanley Yeah, I guees that ))

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. @DStanley. I am just practicing the Ternary and you're right it is easy to do multiple lines to check the code. But I know there is a way to do that and Here at Stack Exchange, I know that many coders here feels the same to Upgrade their knowledge in every way that they can.

Thanks Farhad for the detailed explanation on First FOD and Any Method. Got it to work and now Reading the related methods for them :D

Comment: I will up this as soon as I get 15 reputation. Require for voting :D

Comment: @Aizen Glad to help. You can still mark as an answer, if it solved your problem.  Good luck.

Comment: @Aizen To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want to return one value if the `where` clause returns something and another if not.  That would be:

```
label1.Text = Cclass.TestMe()
                    .Any(t => t.GFName == (textBox1.Text == "" 
                                              ? "GName" 
                                              : textBox1.Text)) ? 
              "Super" : 
              "Nothing";
```

If that's not what you want, then rearrange your code to use `if` statements to make it *work*, then make it *better*.  Ugly working code is *always* better than elegant broken code.